# Select query on Mysql (with innoDB ) in production is hanging and not returning anything even waiting for some minutes

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a mysql DB in production, there's a table A on which a simple select is not returning data. We used mysql console to check via root user. We have tried taking mysqldump that didn't helped and was stuck. Engine is inno DB. Any idea what way we can see the data without changing any indexes? The query must be doing a full scan on the table it seems and we have an index only on Pkey. The select query uses a column other than pkey.

Comment: Please add table definition and query as text. How many rows in table? You say the problem is in production is there the same issue in dev?

Comment: Also provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Table definition and query or explain plan can not be shared due to company policy. Select count(*) is stuck, even select from sys.session is stuck, however select from some other tables is showing records. We have restarted the mysql service, that didn't helped. Our application logs states something unusual - Could not parse the <somedata>'' into a number. Can some bad data can cause this like not even count(*) works ?